# I cant pass all vaues from extra feilds in django Rest allauth framework for custom user model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth, django-custom-user

I created Django custom user model and added restframework to it. Custom User fields are fname, lname, email,username,password,phone ,gender,acctype.
when I register user through the Django restframework, it only takes username,email and password and other field are become empty. what is the problem

> my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager,User

# Create your models here.

GENDER_CHOICES = (
   ('M', 'Male'),
   ('F', 'Female')
)


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, phone, gender, password=None, **extrafields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("email is needed")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("username is needed")
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("Phone is needed")
        if not gender:
            raise ValueError("gender is needed")
        user= self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            phone=phone,
            gender=gender,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,username,phone,gender,password,**extrafields):
        user=self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
            phone=phone,
            gender=gender,

        )
        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    ACCTYPE = (
        ('Student', 'Student'),
        ('Staff', 'Staff')
    )
    fname=models.CharField(verbose_name='fname', max_length=30)
    lname=models.CharField(verbose_name='lname', max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='E-mail', max_length=30, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='Username', max_length=30, unique=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last Login', auto_now=True)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone', max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=128)
    acctype = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ACCTYPE)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email', 'phone', 'gender']
    objects=AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_lebel):
        return True
```

> serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer
from accounts.models import Account

from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer


class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
        fname = serializers.CharField(required=True)
        lname = serializers.CharField(required=True)
        username=serializers.CharField(required=True)
        email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
        password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
        phone=serializers.CharField(required=True)
        gender=serializers.CharField(required=True)
        acctype=serializers.CharField(required=True)

        def get_cleaned_data(self):
            super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
            return {
                'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
                'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
                'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
                'fname': self.validated_data.get('fname', ''),
                'lname': self.validated_data.get('lname', ''),
                'phone': self.validated_data.get('phone', ''),
                'acctype': self.validated_data.get('acctype', ''),
                'gender': self.validated_data.get('gender', ''),
            }

class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Account
            fields = ('pk','email','fname','lname','username','phone','gender','acctype')
            read_only_fields = ('email','acctype','fname','lname')
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView
from .models import Account


# Create your views here.


class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-allauth doesn't allow saving custom fields by default

To solve this problem I refined a **save** function inside **CustomRegisterSerializer** and simply assign the custom field values. Then saved it using user.save()

```
def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])

        user.fname=self.cleaned_data.get('fname')
        user.lname=self.cleaned_data.get('lname')
        user.phone=self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        user.acctype=self.cleaned_data.get('acctype')
        user.gender=self.cleaned_data.get('gender')

        user.save()

        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
serializer.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from accounts.models import Account


class CustomRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = '__all__'


views.py

from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Account
from .serializer import CustomRegisterSerializer # import serializer as your path defined

class CustomRegisterView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomRegisterSerializer
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
```

Comment: its not working. when I run this it shows  : TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`                                                 then I added .as_view({'post': 'list'}) in urls.py. now it not store any values